# Can I add merge fields to the 'setplainTextBody' before I send out email?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, singleemailmessage, merge-field

On a VF page, I am making use of **Custom Metadata Types** and displaying some text to the end users which is going to the input for: `setplainTextBody(subBody)` to enable capability for editing it before  sending out the email.

Using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();` to send out the email to the contacts that are selected from below Wrapper class. I want to make this `subBody` to be one of the merge fields on an email template along with some standard fields: ContactName, Phone and other custom fields. Currently with this: `mail.setplainTextBody(subBody);` I can only send whatever data in that text area.

How can I implement this:

> Dear {!Contact.FirstName},
>
> {!Case.Email_Body__c}  "**This is subBody**"
>
> Case details:
>
> Record Name: {!Kindle__c.Name}
>
> Type of Record: {!Case.Kindle_Type__c}
>
> Record title: {!Case.Subject} 
>   Kindle officer's Contact number: {!Case.KindleConNumb__c}
>
> Extension(If any): {!Case.Extension__c}
>
> Thank you, 
>   {!Kindle__c.OwnerFullName}

EDIT:
This is my new implementation which ended up with an error:

I am getting an error: **SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR, Body: Field cw.con.Name does not exist. Check spelling.: [cw.con.Name]**. This is my code:

```
  if(!atLeastOneSelected){
        for(cContact cw: contactList){
            if(cw.selected == TRUE){
                atLeastOneSelected = true;
                System.debug('Select Con:' +cw.con.Name);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(true);
                mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {cw.con.Email});
                mail.setplainTextBody('Dear {!cw.con.Name}' +subBody );
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Kindler');
                mail.setSubject('Kindle's next Best');
                listEmail.add(mail);
                contactList = null;
            } 
        }  
    }
```

Using the `System.debug` I could see the selected contact's name, but ended up with this error.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [`setTreatBodiesAsTemplate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) method.

> Optional. If set to true, the subject, plain text, and HTML text bodies of the email are treated as template data.

Example usage:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setPlainTextBody('Sending a test to {!Contact.FirstName}');
email.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(true);

// set other properties
// send email
```

Comment: As I already have my email template ready, can I make use of that template(by providing its ID) to send out the email to the selected contacts from the VF page?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. You may have to query the template body, manipulate it, then pass it to your email message instance.

Comment: I was able to query the EmailTemplate and set: `mail.setTemplateId(mailTemp.Id);`, but how can I manipulate it's body now?

Comment: Any suggestions?